# postgresql@10-main.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

```
AWS ubuntu 16.04
PostgreSql 10
```

When I'm trying to executing

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql@10-main.service
```

I'm getting this message.

*Job for postgresql@10-main.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded.
See "systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*

```
systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
```

When getting this message

```
postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled; vendor prese
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Sun 2018-08-19 11:25:39 +06; 1min 44s 
   Process: 25828 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i sta

Aug 19 11:25:39 ip-172-31-46-211 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main..
Aug 19 11:25:39 ip-172-31-46-211 postgresql@10-main[25828]: Error: /usr/lib/postgr
Aug 19 11:25:39 ip-172-31-46-211 postgresql@10-main[25828]: 2018-08-19 11:25:39.09
Aug 19 11:25:39 ip-172-31-46-211 postgresql@10-main[25828]: pg_ctl: could not star
Aug 19 11:25:39 ip-172-31-46-211 postgresql@10-main[25828]: Examine the log output
Aug 19 11:25:39 ip-172-31-46-211 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: PID file 
Aug 19 11:25:39 ip-172-31-46-211 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10
Aug 19 11:25:39 ip-172-31-46-211 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Unit ente
Aug 19 11:25:39 ip-172-31-46-211 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed wi
```

It was running 3 days ago but suddenly it's not working and I can't access the database.

How can resolve the issue?

Comment: Your log is not complete. May You edit it please?

Comment: Aug 19 12:20:35 ip-172-31-46-211 postgresql@10-main[26001]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/l
Aug 19 12:20:35 ip-172-31-46-211 postgresql@10-main[26001]: 2018-08-19 12:20:35.689 +06 [26009] FATAL:  could not create lock file "postmaster.pid": P
Aug 19 12:20:35 ip-172-31-46-211 postgresql@10-main[26001]: pg_ctl: could not start server
Aug 19 12:20:35 ip-172-31-46-211 postgresql@10-main[26001]: Examine the log output.

Comment: does lock file exist?

Comment: postmaster.pid ? and which location?

Comment: In my OS there is no var after local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178284/discussion-between-mahfuz-ahmed-and-rcordoval).

Comment: Just look at the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: Any solution? I am facing the same issue